# Why Facebook oauth returns to returnUrl without parameters?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

While doing login with facebook in my webapp, my oAuth authentication seems to work in that Facebook successfully returns to my returnUrl page. But alas facebook returns back to my page without any parameters. It only returns like:

> =">http://myabc.com/fb/fbReturn.aspx#*=*

Facebook is not even returning any error. Help please.

update:
The behavior shows only in live site. In localhost there is no problem.

Comment: Are you sure your site isn't performing a redirect?

Comment: Sure, ya, because same code is working with localhost but problem shows up with the live website.